# PostGIS equivalent of Pandas geometry.area for square feet

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geopandas, area

I have a Python script that has a line that takes the geometry and calculates it into a square feet value by multiplying the area by 10.7639 in a geopandas dataframe.

```
bldg_feat_poly_df['bldg_sqft'] = bldg_feat_poly_df.geometry.area * 10.7639
```

This works fine. I am now trying to do the same in PostgreSQL using PostGIS. I believe that ST_Area is the correct method to use:

```
SELECT
ST_Area(geom) * 10.7639 AS bldg_sqft
FROM my_schema.my_table
```

Looking at the ST_Area [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html) , it looks like it automatically calculates the value as square feet. My geometry is already in SRID=102008/North America Albers Equal Area Conic projection. Should I just use `ST_Area(geom)  AS bldg_sqft` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`st_area` is the correct function to use to get a geometry area, expressed in the CRS unit.

[102008](https://epsg.io/102008) unit is `meters`, so the output will be in square meters, and you would still have to apply the conversion factor

Comment: So, `ST_Area(geom) * 10.7639 AS bldg_sqft` would be correct then?

Comment: yes, as 1m2 = 10.7639ft2